# Python - How can I check if a UTC date string is correct?

Tags: python, date, utc

I receive a date value on a `POST` request, and it has this format `20220509T000000Z`.

In the system where I am working on, sometimes users can send wrong date values like `2022059T000000Z` and `2022509T000000Z`. That date is saved as string on our database, but if it is incorrect we get issues later doing some calculations and displaying information.

So, I am looking for a way in Python to validate the string is a correct date format, something like this:

```
#parameter date is the string I receive on the POST
def validate(date):
    if date is valid:
        # a valid date would be 20220509T000000Z
        return true
    else:
        # an incorrect date would be 2022509T000000Z
        return 'Error, incorrect date values'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use dateutil parser in a try and except:

```
import dateutil

#parameter date is the string I receive on the POST
def validate(date):
    try:
        dateutil.parser.parse(date)
        # a valid date would be 20220509T000000Z
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        # an incorrect date would be 2022509T000000Z
        return 'Error, incorrect date values'
```

Comment: I don't think its invalid date according to parsers.

Comment: I used the dateutil.parser.parse with 20220509T000000Z but it returns False.

Comment: correct this is giving correct output.

Comment: for me
dateutil.parser.parse('20220509T000000Z')
returns: datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 9, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzutc())
could you send the exact error code

Comment: Oh, it works! sorry, I made a mistake replicating your answer, that's why I was getting errors.